# How stop another function from an UIButton function using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, function, uibutton

I got two functions running called updatePrice and updateTime, and I want to stop them when I click an UIButton.

```
func updateTime() {...}
func updatePrice() {...}

// ..

@IBAction func Button(sender: UIButton) { 

    // What should I write here? 

}
```

Comment: If `updateTime` and `updatePrice` are running on the main thread, `Button` won't even actually be called until after they're done executing...

Comment: All are in a ViewController class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like `NSOperation`s do: make a boolean and periodically check it in those functions. Something like:

```
var stopFuncs = false
```

and later in functions at sensitive moments insert that:

```
if stopFuncs { return }
```

and add this to button code:

```
stopFuncs = true
```

Comment: how can I do that with NSOperation? Could you please give me an example? Thanks for help

Comment: @ArasSerdaroğlu I meant to say that NSOperation's `main` functions work like that. Just try to accomplish that using the tips I gave you.

Comment: @ArasSerdaroğlu and, of course, if the functions run on the main thread they won't be interrupted by a button, because they don't run concurrently.

Comment: Better go for a tutorial and understand the concept of NSOperation and NSOperationQueue. You can achieve this using these two classes.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did it by using a new return value, however functions still running in background. They still calculate updated values